# Mongodb, reduce a result with another result

Tags: mongodb

I m actually writing a simple application, and I need to reduce the result of a request with the result of another one and I dont know what is the best way to handle that.

**Explanations** :

I have two collections :

- User : {_id, name, surname}
- Car : {_id, model, #refOnUser}

I want to get all the user that are not in a car record.
It means that I want all the user that doesn't have a car.

**My Solution** :

- Make a request on Car, and getting a list of cars
- Make a request on User and getting a list of users with something like "not in" the array of user id from the car list

Is this a good solution ?

Does exist something better ?

Comment: you should have a look on mongoDB schema design : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/

Answer (score 1):

From design perspective for NoSQL databases, you should make a single collection User.

> Case 1 :  If there is one to one relationship between User and Car:

you can maintain ***car as embeddable in user*** and have something like this :

```
User : {_id, name, surname, Car : {_id, model, #refOnUser}}
```

> Case 2 :  If there is one to many relationship between User and Car:

you can maintain ***car as List of embeddable in user*** and have something like this :

```
User : {_id, name, surname, Car : [{_id, model, #refOnUser},....]}
```